# How to get the name of a field?

Tags: 8, entities

I'm on `hook_form_alter` for the config edit form. The code runs for all fields, but it's critical that the code figures out the name of the field it is on.

When I load the formobject, I can see the `field_name` perfectly when I `print_r` the array. But I can't figure out how to pull it out. Something like `$name=$field['field_name']`

The field name is 'field_plan_purpose' I need to get that in a variable in the code.

My code minus all of things I've tried:

```
$field = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
print '<pre>';
print_r($field);
print '</pre>';
```

Here is the top part of the array that gets printed:

```
Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig Object
(
    [deleted:protected] => 
    [fieldStorage:protected] => Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig Object
        (
            [id:protected] => node.field_plan_purpose
            [field_name:protected] => field_plan_purpose <--- HOW DO I GET THIS
            [entity_type:protected] => node
            [type:protected] => text_long
            [module:protected] => text
            [settings:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [cardinality:protected] => 1
            [translatable:protected] => 1
            [locked:protected] => 
            [persist_with_no_fields:protected] => 
            [custom_storage] => 
            [indexes:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [deleted:protected] => 
            [schema:protected] => 
            [propertyDefinitions:protected] => Array
                (...
```

As you can see, 'field_name' is in there. Does anyone know how I can pull that out and reference it directly?

A few things I've tried:

```
    // print_r($field->getEntityKey('#field_name'));
    // getEntityType()->getKey('field_name')
    // $field['field_name']  $field['field_name:protected']
    // $field['id']
    // $field->getKey('field_name')
    // $field->definition['field_name'];
    // print_r($field->definition);
```

EDITED ******* SOLUTION

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

   $field = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
   $field_name = $field->getName();
   print $field_name;

}
```

Comment: From all the things you tried (at the bottom): you didn't include the leading "//", did you? If so, no surprise none of them returned what you were looking for ... Please edit your question to correct that .. if indeed you did not include those leading chars ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FieldConfigBase`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigBase.php/class/FieldConfigBase/8.2.x) has a method named [`getName()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldConfigBase.php/function/FieldConfigBase%3A%3AgetName/8.2.x). That will retrieve the field name:

```
public function getName() {
  return $this->field_name;
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks man, this works. I can't believe I couldn't figure that out lol. Final solution for getting entity field_name from hook_form_alter in Drupal 8 is edited in the original post up top.